# PHP Video Source with Video.js Without Downloading Entire File First

Tags: javascript, php, video.js

I am giving Video.js a source from PHP using:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Content-Length: $length");

readfile("$url");
exit;
```

However, the video will not start playing until it is fully downloaded. How can I get Video.js to commence playback immediately without waiting for file to fully download?

Comment: Lots of variables here. It may even be due to the way the .mp4 is encoded, ie if the metadata block is not at the beginning of the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/58047449/13695921

Comment: If I give it the direct mp4 file link, it works fine. The stream begins immediately and does not wait for download. It is when I use a php script to fetch file and send to video.js that the problem occurs.